# AFNetworking session iOS7 to stay logged in

Tags: php, ios, session, afnetworking

I'm coding an iOS app, and to do so I would like to have a login part.
I have a form with an email and a password which are send to my PHP with AFNetworking, I check in PHP if it is in the database, and php send back a response to xcode in JSON with the ID, the mail and the password of the person. (of course only if they exists and match) 
Now my question is how can I do to keep the person logged in, I mean that she doesn't have to put her email and her password anymore ?
Is it possible to do it with AFNetworking session management ? Or do I have to use NSUsers ? or a cookie ?

thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Save the username and password in NSUserDefaults and fetch them when you need them